# makefile change working directory, python

Tags: makefile

that runs multiple python scripts but I have a slight problem. my python one of my scripts creates/writes to a sql database that is in the scripts directory. but when I use make file a database is created in the makefiles's directory and not the python script's directory. so how can I change the makefile's working directory?

this is a map of my file:

```html
+ ProjectFile
|---+ make file 
|---+ database (unwanted)
|---+ PythonScript1
    |---+ main.py python script
    |---+ (where a database should be))
|---+ PythonScript2
    |---+ main.py python script
    |---+ (where a database should be))
|---+ PythonScript3
    |---+ main.py python script
    |---+ (where a database should be)
```

this is my makefile:

```html
PYTHON       = python3
TERMINAL = gnome-terminal
TFLAG = --
FOLDERS = server
LIST = a b c d e

run:
    for dir in $(FOLDERS); do \
        cd $${dir} \
        ${TERMINAL} ${TFLAG} ${PYTHON} main.py ; \
    done
```

I had an idea of changing directories in my for loop but then I read that it isnt necessary. So how can I change the working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt the comment you read was talking about a different situation than yours.

You don't, in general, want to change make's working directory.  Instead you should change the working directory of the command you invoke (if it needs to be run from a specific directory).

The makefile recipe you've posted is very confusing: you have variables assigned to names that are different than what you show in your example, and some are not used at all.  The recipe you use is *almost* correct, but it contains a shell error so I'm sure it doesn't run.  You can do this as:

```
run:
        for dir in $(FOLDERS); do \
            cd $${dir} ; \
            ${TERMINAL} ${TFLAG} ${PYTHON} main.py ; \
        done
```

Note the semicolon after the `cd` command.  You can also change this to `&&` to be a little safer (so that it doesn't run the command if the `cd` fails).

In general, this is not a very make-like makefile.  You might as well just use a shell script here since you're not taking advantage of any of make's actual features.

Also, it's *highly* unusual to start a graphical terminal from a makefile to run commands in.  Why are you doing that?

I would write this something like:

```
FOLDERS := PythonScript1 PythonScript2 PythonScript3

run: $(FOLDERS)

$(FOLDERS):
        cd $@ && $(PYTHON) main.py

.PHONY: run $(FOLDERS)
```

Comment: "Also, it's highly unusual to start a graphical terminal from a makefile to run commands in. Why are you doing that?" Sometimes  the scripts print to a terminal and I just want to read the outputs for each of scripts.

Comment: But... once the script is complete the terminal will exit and your outputs will all be gone...???  If you want to read the output why not just look at it on the screen where you ran make, or redirect the output to a file so you can look at it later?

Comment: they will be redirected to a file later on. its just faster for me to glance at a terminal for now